# Программное нажатие мыши C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Делаю приложение на Windows Forms. Цель приложения - заменить кнопки мыши на клавиши клавиатуры.

Снизу мой код рабочий, но мне одно не нравится.
С моей кодом в интернете сидеть норм! Кликать туда, сюда клавишами классно :3 (*особенно ночью, клавиатура очень тихая, если сравнивать с мышью*).

Проблема такая, **когда я нажимаю *программно* правую кнопку мыши, вылезает контекстное меню** и по нужной вкладке нажимаю *программно* левой кнопкой мыши, но почему-то не кликается, а кликается на **фон, за контекстным меню**. *Это ко всему относится, а не только к браузеру (я только пример из браузера показал)*. Не подумайте плохого, не вина браузера. [image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

***Ещё проблема***, когда хочу открыть файл или папку, вместо этого, открывается информация(характеристики(properties)) о папке и т. д.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу прощения, если излагался не корректно. Я новичок и многое не понимаю.

Использовал `user32.dll`

Код:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]

static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, int dx, int dy, uint dwData, int dwExtraInfo);

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // нажатие на клавишу
            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightAlt))
            {

                mouse_event(0x0002, 1200, 1200, 0, 0);
                Thread.Sleep(150);
                mouse_event(0x0004, 1200, 1200, 0, 0);
            }

            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl))
            {
               
                mouse_event(0x0008, 800, 800, 0, 0);
                Thread.Sleep(150);
                mouse_event(0x00010, 800, 800, 0, 0);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А координаты мыши при передаче события клика не задаются. Вот вам готовый класс управления мышью, откопал из старых проектов.

```
public static class MouseInterface
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool GetCursorPos(out Win32Point lpPoint);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool SetCursorPos(int x, int y);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern void mouse_event(MouseFlags dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, uint dwExtraInfo);
    [Flags]
    private enum MouseFlags : uint
    {
        MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000,   // If set, dx and dy contain normalized absolute coordinates between 0 and 65535. The event procedure maps these coordinates onto the display surface. Coordinate (0,0) maps onto the upper-left corner of the display surface, (65535,65535) maps onto the lower-right corner.
        MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002,   // The left button is down.
        MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004,     // The left button is up.
        MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020, // The middle button is down.
        MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = 0x0040,   // The middle button is up.
        MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001,       // Movement occurred.
        MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008,  // The right button is down.
        MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x0010,    // The right button is up.
        MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL = 0x0800,      // The wheel has been moved, if the mouse has a wheel.The amount of movement is specified in dwData
        MOUSEEVENTF_XDOWN = 0x0080,      // An X button was pressed.
        MOUSEEVENTF_XUP = 0x0100,        // An X button was released.
        MOUSEEVENTF_HWHEEL = 0x01000     // The wheel button is tilted.
    }
        

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct Win32Point
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;
    };
    private static Win32Point GetMousePosition()
    {
        GetCursorPos(out Win32Point w32Mouse);
        return w32Mouse;
    }

    public struct Position
    {
        public static int X { get { return GetMousePosition().X; } }
        public static int Y { get { return GetMousePosition().Y; } }
    }

    public static void ScrollDown()
    {
        mouse_event(MouseFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL, 0, 0, -120, 0);
        Thread.Sleep(50);
    }

    public static void ScrollUp()
    {
        mouse_event(MouseFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL, 0, 0, 120, 0);
        Thread.Sleep(50);
    }

    public static void LeftDown()
    {
        mouse_event(MouseFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    public static void LeftUp()
    {
        mouse_event(MouseFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    public static void RightDown()
    {
        mouse_event(MouseFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    public static void RightUp()
    {
        mouse_event(MouseFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    public static void MiddleDown()
    {
        mouse_event(MouseFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    public static void MiddleUp()
    {
        mouse_event(MouseFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    public static void LeftClick()
    {
        LeftDown();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        LeftUp();
    }

    public static void RightClick()
    {
        RightDown();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        RightUp();
    }

    public static void MiddleClick()
    {
        MiddleDown();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        MiddleUp();
    }

    public static void MoveTo(int X, int Y)
    {
        SetCursorPos(X,Y);
    }

    public static void Move(int X, int Y)
    {
        SetCursorPos(Position.X + X, Position.Y + Y);
    }

    public static void SmoothMove(int X, int Y, int moveTime)
    {
        if (moveTime <= 0) moveTime = 500; else moveTime *= 1000;
        if (moveTime > 30000) moveTime = 30000;
        double rateDelay = 1000 / 60; // 1 sec div by framerate (60)
        int stepsCount = (int)(moveTime / rateDelay);
        int posX = 0, posY = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= stepsCount; i++)
        {
            int oldX = posX;
            int oldY = posY;
            double pos = -(Math.Cos(Math.PI * i / stepsCount) - 1) / 2;
            posX = (int)(X * pos);
            posY = (int)(Y * pos);
            Move(posX - oldX, posY - oldY);
            Thread.Sleep((int)rateDelay);
        }
    }

    public static void SmoothMoveTo(int X, int Y, int moveTime)
    {
        SmoothMove(X - Position.X, Y - Position.Y, moveTime);
    }
}
```

Пользоваться так

```
MouseInterface.MoveTo(1200, 1200);
MouseInterface.LeftClick();
```

То есть сначала переместить, потом тыкнуть.

Кстати, метод Win API `mouse_event` хоть и поддерживается до сих пор, но является устаревшим, актуальный метод - `SendInput`, но пользоваться им немного сложнее. Когда-нибудь я этот класс, опубликованный выше, под него перепишу, а пока и так работает.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @MilkRen кстати, вместо структуры `Win32Point` если у вас Winforms, можете использовать `System.Drawing.Point` и выкинуть мою структуру, немного упростив код. Я писал класс под WPF без System.Drawing, поэтому структура своя.