# c# Неожиданное поведение mouse_event MOVE

Tags: c#, mouse-event

Есть тестовый проект, который просто перемещает мышь через mouse_event на 100 пикселей вперед и низ. Но координаты после выполнения этого метода получаются совсем не такими, как я ожидал. Помогите найти ошибку

Код:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace mouse_move_test
{
    class Program
    {
        const int ABSOLUTE = 0x00008000;
        const int MOVE = 0x00000001;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool GetCursorPos(out MousePoint lpMousePoint);

        public static MousePoint GetCursorPosition()
        {
            MousePoint currentMousePoint;
            var gotPoint = GetCursorPos(out currentMousePoint);
            if (!gotPoint) { currentMousePoint = new MousePoint(0, 0); }
            return currentMousePoint;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct MousePoint
        {
            public int X;
            public int Y;

            public MousePoint(int x, int y)
            {
                X = x;
                Y = y;
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int dt = 100;


            // Тест относительных координат
            Console.WriteLine($"Тест относительных координат");
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                var pos = GetCursorPosition();
                Console.WriteLine($"{pos.X} {pos.Y} - текущая позиция");
                Console.WriteLine($"{pos.X + dt} {pos.Y + dt} - ожидание");

                mouse_event(MOVE, dt, dt, 0, 0);

                pos = GetCursorPosition();
                Console.WriteLine($"{pos.X} {pos.Y} - реальность");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            // Тест абсолютных координат
            Console.WriteLine($"Тест абсолютных координат");
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                var pos = GetCursorPosition();
                Console.WriteLine($"{pos.X} {pos.Y} - текущая позиция");
                Console.WriteLine($"{pos.X + dt} {pos.Y + dt} - ожидание");

                mouse_event(MOVE | ABSOLUTE, pos.X + dt, pos.Y + dt, 0, 0);

                pos = GetCursorPosition();
                Console.WriteLine($"{pos.X} {pos.Y} - реальность");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }



}
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
Тест относительных координат
0 0 - текущая позиция
100 100 - ожидание
155 155 - реальность

155 155 - текущая позиция
255 255 - ожидание
409 409 - реальность

409 409 - текущая позиция
509 509 - ожидание
664 664 - реальность

Тест абсолютных координат
664 664 - текущая позиция
764 764 - ожидание
22 12 - реальность

22 12 - текущая позиция
122 112 - ожидание
3 1 - реальность

3 1 - текущая позиция
103 101 - ожидание
3 1 - реальность
```

upd.
Я правда пытаюсь) Приложение WPF. Я постараюсь привести упрощенные методы, мб это поможет Есть хук мыши

```
private int MouseHookProc(int nCode, int wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"wParam {wParam}");
        return CallNextHookEx(hMouseHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

Если я вызываю код `mouse_event(0x00000001, 100, 100, 0, 0);` Я получаю в лог `wParam 512` Если использую код `SetCursorPos(100, 100);` То ничего не перехватывается. Что касается SendMessage с ним у меня были какие-то проблемы. Кажется, не работает в играх

dpi у меня 96, как я выяснил. А у координат прирост 50%. Где-то есть масштаб 150% который я пока не знаю как достать

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1436487/373567

Comment: В том коде используется SetCursorPos. Я правильно понимаю, что он и есть MouseMove, а в mouse_event флаг MOVE можно использовать только в тандеме с другими флагами? Т.е. сам по себе как мув он так не сработает? Просто мне казалось его использование вполне логичным

Comment: `mouse_event` работает в логических пикселях, `SetCursorPos` и `GetCursorPos` - в физических. У вас масштаб на мониторе не 100%, поэтому вы получаете такие спецэффекты. Вы можете и `MOVE` использовать, но придется пересчитывать координаты через фактическое значение dpi в отношении к стандартному - 96dpi. То есть ваше значение dpi - 148dpi (но это не точно), его так же можно получить из Win API. Но лучше ничего не пересчитывать, а использовать сразу подходящий метод Win API.

Comment: Кстати `mouse_event` устарел, когда я еще был маленьким, актуальный метод Win API для управления клавиатурой и мышью - `SendInput`. Если хотите правильно реализовать, используйте его, но сразу предупреждаю, он не так прост. Вот [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1248869/373567), для начала.

Comment: Похоже, придется пересчитывать. Так как для меня важно, чтобы это было именно движение, а не смена позиции. SetCursorPos не хукается как смена позиции. За пример с SendInput спасибо. Однажды)

Comment: `SetCursorPos не хукается как смена позиции` Так я вам дал ссылку на код, где все движения реализованы. И на координаты и на смещение. Посмотрите внимательно. Готовый класс, берите и пользуйтесь. Сложно чтоли получить `GetCursorPos`, добавить к нему смещение и вызвать `SetCursorPos`?

Comment: Да, SetCursorPos делает смещение, всё четко по координатам, курсор там где нужно. Но в системе это не регистрируется как событие мыши с кодом 512. Я об этом

Comment: Что значит не регистрируется как событие 512? Я этим кодом кликал по всякому, работало как часы. Вы про сообщение WM_MOUSEMOVE? Тогда это не в методе SetCursorPos проблема, а в том что у вас код возможно неправильно написан, вы какой тип приложения используете для этого?

Comment: Вы не прислушались к моему совету задать отдельный вопрос, вместо этого изменили текущий и мой ответ, данный ранее, превратился в мусор. Жаль, но больше на вопросы, которые меняются после выдачи ответа, я отвечать не намерен, пустая трата времени. Теперь ваш вопрос содержит 2 вопроса, и его необходимо конкретизировать, в противном случае он будет закрыт. Если ничего не помогает, попробуйте `SendInput`, как я советовал ранее.

Comment: Тот ответ не бы мусором. Просто он решал проблему только отчасти. Моей ошибкой было то, что я не указал, что мне нужно имитировать реальное движение мыши. Я не ожидал, что обсуждение уйдёт от моего кода. Но, согласитесь, вопрос мой заключался в том, почему в моем коде с координатами беда, а не как мне переместить мышь

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1918890/12888024

Comment: Спасибо. Увы, я ошибся, и дело не в масштабе. Какой-то нелинейный коэффициент взрывает мне голову. На перемещении 100 он даёт 155, а на 200 - 317, на 300 - 480. Никакой пропорции. В любом случае, спасибо за уделенное время. На сегодня у меня руки опустились. Мб завтра со свежей головой что-то выйдет. Простите, если что не так.
Кстати, поведение оказалось одинаковым хоть для консоли, хоть для wpf, хоть для mouse_event, хоть для SendInput

Comment: Добавьте минимальную задержку между манипуляциями с мышью, если их несколько. Хук может не сразу реагировать на сообщения. Используйте асинхронное ожидание `await Task.Delay()` не используйте `Thread.Sleep`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, проблему удалось решить через флаг абсолютных координат, хотя поведения без него с непропорциональными коэффициентами я так и не раскусил. Информацию нашел сначала тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62626388/c-sharp-winapi-mouse-event
потом уже и в справке https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event в ремарке. Кстати там же есть что-то полезное и про относительные координаты (без флага), но я уже не мог. Имея рабочий вариант с абсолютными координатами уже не проблема использовать его и для относительных.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace mouse_move_test
{
    class Program
    {
        const int ABSOLUTE = 0x00008000;
        const int MOVE = 0x00000001;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int GetSystemMetrics(int nIndex);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool GetCursorPos(out MousePoint lpMousePoint);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool SetCursorPos(int x, int y);

        public static MousePoint GetCursorPosition()
        {
            MousePoint currentMousePoint;
            var gotPoint = GetCursorPos(out currentMousePoint);
            if (!gotPoint) { currentMousePoint = new MousePoint(0, 0); }
            return currentMousePoint;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);


        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct MousePoint
        {
            public int X;
            public int Y;

            public MousePoint(int x, int y)
            {
                X = x;
                Y = y;
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int dt = 100;

            // получаем разрешение экрана
            int sx = GetSystemMetrics(0);
            int sy = GetSystemMetrics(1);


            // Тест относительных координат
            Console.WriteLine($"Тест абсолютных координат");
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                SetCursorPos(0, 0);
                var pos = GetCursorPosition();
                Console.WriteLine($"{pos.X} {pos.Y} - текущая позиция");
                Console.WriteLine($"{pos.X + dt} {pos.Y + dt} - ожидание");

                int x = (int)Math.Ceiling(65536d / sx * dt);
                int y = (int)Math.Ceiling(65536d / sy * dt);

                mouse_event(MOVE | ABSOLUTE, x, y, 0, 0);

                pos = GetCursorPosition();
                Console.WriteLine($"{pos.X} {pos.Y} - реальность");
                Console.WriteLine();

                dt += 100;
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод

```
Тест абсолютных координат
0 0 - текущая позиция
100 100 - ожидание
100 100 - реальность

0 0 - текущая позиция
200 200 - ожидание
200 200 - реальность

0 0 - текущая позиция
300 300 - ожидание
300 300 - реальность
```