# Как имитировать нажатие мыши в консольном приложении C#?

Tags: c#

У меня проблема, нигде не могу найти нормальный гайд "Как имитировать
щелчок мыши в **консольном** приложении на C#".

Пример:

```
string process = "notepad";

Console.WriteLine("Запуск!");
Thread.Sleep(6000);

if (Process.GetProcessesByName(process).Length > 0)
{
Console.WriteLine("Работает!");
Thread.Sleep(60000);
#Здесь должно произойти нажатие левой кнопки мыши
Thread.Sleep(6000);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
Environment.Exit(0);

}
else
{
Console.WriteLine("Не работает!");
Thread.Sleep(6000);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
Environment.Exit(0);

}
```

Comment: с какой целью нажатие кнопки мыши? С целью сделать окно активным?

Comment: а вообще мишке пофиг на то что там за окно - она кликает по координатам экрана https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272681/how-can-i-simulate-a-mouse-click-at-a-certain-position-on-the-screen но подозреваю что ты роешь не в ту сторону

Comment: @Andrew_STOP_RU_AGRESSION_IN_UA https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1436487/373567 у нас тоже такого добра навалом, есть даже такое https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1248869/373567

Comment: `Environment.Exit(0);` - добром это не кончится, научитесь выходить из приложения нормально. Как и `Thread.Sleep`.